# Why does the "location" property end up in Object.keys() after I include jQuery to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<script>
    console.log( Object.keys( this ) );
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log( Object.keys( this ) );
</script>
```

In Firefox, the console logs this:

```
[ "window", "document", "InstallTrigger", "console", "getInterface" ]
[ "window", "document", "InstallTrigger", "console", "getInterface", "location", "$", "jQuery" ]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eX8jQ/

Notice how three additional elements are returned by `Object.keys(this)` after jQuery executes. I understand why `"$"`, and `"jQuery"` are added, but why `"location"`?

I also tested in Chrome, and IE10. In both, only `"$"`, and `"jQuery"` are added.

Comment: In chrome and IE10, location is already part of that. Or am i missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/eX8jQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.9.1 contains the following in its internal initialization code:

```
var location = window.location;
```

In the toplevel context, `this` is `window`, so you're testing `Object.keys(window)`. Apparently Firefox treats the `window.location` property magically -- it doesn't show up in `keys` unless it's accessed. So a side effect of the above assignment is to cause it to appear there.

This local variable is not in jQuery 1.11.1 or jQuery 2.1.1, so simply loading jQuery should not have this side effect.

Answer (score -1):

In firefox, Location isn't in the keys by default, however in Chrome and IE it's there to begin with. Test this in Chrome and IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/eX8jQ/1/ And also in your fiddle, you can see Location in chrome and ie, it just isn't in the same location in the array.

and because i must include code to post this...

```
<script>
    console.log( Object.keys( this ) );
</script>
```

*I haven't actually tested this in IE10, I don't have access to it at the moment.*

Comment: Yes. My question is, though, what does jQuery do to make it appear in Firefox? Notice how the `location` global property *does* exist in Firefox, it's just that it doesn't appear in `Object.keys()`. However, once jQuery executes, it does appear.

Comment: Heh. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/eX8jQ/4/ It seems that mere access makes the `location` property appear in `Object.keys()`.

Comment: How is that relevant here? When you explicitly create a new global property (either via `var foo` in global code, or via assignment to `window.foo`), that property will show up in `Object.keys()`. But `location` is a built-in global property which only shows up *after* it's accessed.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas So i guess your real question is, *why doesn't location show up in Object.keys to begin with in firefox*. If you look at the jQuery core, you can see where location is being accessed, which makes it properly show up (in addition to the two added global vars `jQuery` and `$`).

Comment: I'd suggest narrowing this question down to not include jQuery and focus on the real issue.